# c# Intellisense options for COM applications

Tags: c#, vba, com

I created a c# class library in VS2015, with one class:

```
namespace A_JAM_CLASS_LIB
{
    public class base_class
    {
        public string a_method()
        {
            return "Hi!";
        }
    }
}
```

I built this solution with COM registration and selecting "make assembly COM-visible"

And I'm now in Excel and I'm able to do run this without a hitch:

```
Public Sub test()
  Dim x As New A_JAM_CLASS_LIB.base_class
  MsgBox x.a_method
End Sub
```

The biggest thing I don't understand is that there's no intellisense for my "x" object even though it has been dimensioned.

So my question is - how can I specify my app to provide intellisense options?

Does it require the regasm process? Would I need clients to use regasm?